# string replace sql select

Tags: sql, select, replace, prepend

Hi Ive tried to find an answer to this but cant find one.

Id like to remove some characters and prepend a pound sign to the result of an SQL query which looks as follows (its already using a replace command can I stack these)?:

```
select fundraiser.Company_Name, 
       replace(Just_Giving_Campaign,'"label":',''),  
       sum(fundraising_campaigns.Total_Collected) as donations
from fundraising_campaigns, 
     fundraiser
where Charity_Name = 'WaterAid' 
  and fundraising_campaigns.Campaigners_ID = fundraiser.id
group by fundraiser.Company_Name
```

Can anyone confirm how I would go about adding (£ sign) and remove several sets of characters from a select statement.Certainly dont appear to be able to stack replace statements (e.g.

replace(replace (string, what to match, what to replace it with), what to match, what to replace it with)

Appreciate any thoughts

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: well i quite did not get what you want , but if you need nested replace in 1 sql statement, those are indeed supported in MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your question. If I am correct you want to prepend `£` and do some nested replace. Hope the below example helps.

```
select '£'+replace(replace('YourText','x','s'),'You','U')
```